# Using apt-get from ISO on vmware

Tags: installation, apt, vmware, iso

I'm trying to install VLAN using `apt-get` but I get this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package vlan
```

I'm not connected to the Internet at the moment as I need to tag my Ubuntu server to the VLAN first. I've installed Ubuntu on VMWare using an ISO file.

Is there a way I can install applications using apt-get from the ISO file?

Answer (score 2):

You can install packages that are contained on the CD. vlan package is most likely not present on the iso for you to install. So you would have to use an offline method to install that package: 
If you need to download Ubuntu packages using another machine or OS, check the desired packages in Synaptic and select File > Generate package download script. Alternatively, try http://ubottu.com/ljl/apt/

Comment: Having installe the vlan package from the recommended site (http://ubottu.com/ljl/apt/), im now having problems tagging the vlan. after editing the file in /etc/network/interfaces, I get the error "Set name-type for VLAN subsystem. Should be visible in /proc/net/vlan/config....RTNETLINK answers: File exists...Failed to bring up vlan340"

Comment: @WilliamC that deserves another question. If this answer can help you to solve the offline package installation issue, please accept it and open another question for the upcoming issue.